# Cant put users ID as FK for added database entry (bind added entry to currently loggedin user) - Hibernate, Spring, Spring Security -

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a small library management system where users log in and add books from their collection. I am using Spring Boot with Spring Security, MySql and Hibernate. Users are able to login and when they are logged in I can take their info via ContexHolder and I can add books to database and get them all and display them in front-end, but now I want to bind every added book with currently logged in user so I can display only books this user has added, not all books from db. I am trying to do it like this:

My BookController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @Resource
    BookDAO bookDao;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HashMap<String, String> addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        book.setUser(new Security().getCurrentUser());
        bookDao.save(book);
        return Response.setSuccess("Book saved successfuly.");
    }
```

My Security.java:

```
public class Security {

    private UserDAO userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getCurentUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return userDao.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    }

}
```

But, for some reason, in this case, method getCurrentUser returns null and I get NullPointerException. But when I use the same method from UserController.java it returns exactly what I expect i to return. This is tested at the same run (first I called a method from Securty.java and it returned null, then I called method from UserControll.java and I got currently logged in user (me) ).

Here is my UserController.java (only getCurrentUser and loginUser methods):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Resource
    private UserDAO userDao;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getCurentUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return userDao.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    }

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public HashMap<String, String> loginUser(@RequestBody final User user) {
        final User foundUser = userDao.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (foundUser == null || !encoder.matches(user.getCurentPassword(), foundUser.getCurentPassword())) {
            return Response.setError("Bad credentials");
        } else {
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getCurentPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(foundUser.getRole().name()));
            final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            return Response.setSuccess(foundUser.getRole().name());
        }
    }
```

Oh, and my Book.Java bean:

```
....
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after long time of trying i have managed to solve this problem. As it turned out - calling getCurrentUser method from separate Security class returned anonymous user even thou user with ROLE_USER was logged in. Adding @Autowired annots to UserDAO userDao or @Component or @Service annots to whole class also did not gave any results.
Calling:

```
userDao.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName())
```

from BookController with UserDAO userDao eith @Resource annot in BookController also returned anonymous user. Only when I added @Autowired to UserDAO userDao i managed to get currently logged in user and bind book to him. Here is the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @Resource
    BookDAO bookDao;

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDao;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public HashMap<String, String> addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        book.setUser(userDao.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()));
        bookDao.save(book);
        return Response.setSuccess("Book saved successfuly.");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this is not the best way of doing it but in the moment of writing this post it was the only way of doing it. :)

Answer (score -1):

1- The class `Security` has a `@Component` or `@Service` annotation?

2- `userDao` field is null - you need to inject it using `@Autowired` to avoid `NullPointerException` in `getCurrentUser()` method.

Comment: Class Security has NO annotation. Should I put some and why? I will try now @Autowired ...

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Changed to @Autowired - still null.